# Asp.Net web core Url of images on localhost and on the domain produce different results

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I keep photos in the subfolder lib/photos of the wwwroot folder of my website.
Now when I run on localhost, using

```
<img src="/lib/photos/myphoto.jpg" />
```

in my razor view works fine and shows the picture.

But when I run on my domain, I have installed the application in a **subfolder** of the domain, that would be: http://www.example.com/photosite/

in this case the same code in the razor view:

```
<img src="/lib/photos/myphoto.jpg" />
```

does not show the picture.

I thought that that should not make any difference but it does.
How can I determine the right relative path of the picture when my website runs in a subfolder of my domain? How can I do that programmatically, since the urls of the pictures are dynamically loaded from database.

Comment: What is the url it is trying to load from ? (Right click on the image and select "open in new tab")

Comment: In local host I have: localhostxxxxx/lib/photos/myphoto.jpg   and online I have http://www.example.com/lib/photos/myphoto.jpg  obviously the second one is not found. I need to add photosite in between the domain and the lib/photos parts

Comment: You can use a config setting to specify the base path for the image. Each environment would have a different config value.

Comment: I found the Request.PathBase at hand to solve my problem.